# Соблюдение размера при генерации произвольной последовательности звуков

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте. Проблема следующая: нужно ввести в код условие, при котором воспроизводимые звуки будут разбиваться на такты. Я уже подумал над осуществлением этого через суммирование переменных *N*, *равным секундам звучания сэмпла* (см. пример кода) и сравнение суммы *N* с переменной *R* (`R = (float(60)/float(tempo)*4)`, где **минута / темп * 4** (число 4 для размера 4/4; длительность такта в таком случае при темпе в 120 ударов = 2 секунды, в 60 ударов = 4 с, и т.д.)). Но не могу понять, как осуществить такую операцию. Тем более, на мой взгляд, при её выполнении возможны превышения значения *R* суммой *N*, что не приемлемо и равносильно сбиванию с такта.

Другой вариант -- генерировать список произвольных чисел (`random.shuffle`), сумма которого равна *R* и присвоить к каждому числу переменную. Однако в таком случае числа, отвечающие за продолжительность звуков не смогут повторяться.

---

```
import pyglet
import random
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)


def tempo():
    global tempo
    tempo = input("Adjust tempo: ") # Определяется темп.
    play()

def play():
    M = int(random.choice(("1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64", "128", "256"))) # Произвольно выбирается продолжительность звука (целая, вторая, четвёртая и т.д.).
    N = (float(60)/M/float(tempo)) # Минута / продолжительность звука / темп; Таким образом определяется время звучания одного звука в секундах.


    num=random.randint(1,9) # Выбор номера воспроизводимого звука.

    print tempo, num, M, N # Выводит темп, номер воспроизводимого звука, его продолжительность в музыкальном измерении и в секундах.

    if num==1: file = 'D:\\Sound.wav' # Присвоение файла к номеру звука.
    ##. . . . . . .
    if num==9: time.sleep(N), play() # Если 9, то пауза на N; Возвращается в play().


    wavfile = file # Воспроизведение звука.
    sound = pyglet.media.load(wavfile)
    core = pyglet.media.Player()
    core.queue(sound)
    core.play()
    play()


tempo()
```

---

Так же возникает ошибка *IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files*.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить основную задачу и что делать с ошибкой?

Comment: Не понял, что значит "разбить звук на такты", если у вас сэмплы неопределенной длины.  Как должен звучать, к примеру, монотонный "ля" длиной 60 секунд, если частота выбрана 1 секунда?

Comment: Там не очень удачно написано. Лучше сказать "последовательность звуков разбивается на такты".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвлечемся на минутку от теории музыки и слегка переформулируем задачу.

По сути нам нужно в некоторый размер (в данном случае, 4/4 == 1.0) упаковать набор чисел от 1/1 до 1/256 (от 1/(2 в степени 0) до 1/(2 в степени 8)), т.е. сумма нашего ряда чисел должна быть равна некоторому заданному числу.

Это можно сделать так:

```
import random

def split_time(t):
    while t > 0:
        d = t + 1 # Начальное число, заведомо попадающее в условие цикла
        while d > t:
            d = 1.0 / 2**random.randint(0, 8)  # Случайная длительность от 1/1 до 1/256
        yield d
        t -= d
```

Код, я думаю, должен быть вам понятен, за исключением yield. Про yield можно почитать, например, здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/132554/

Как с этим работать? Например, мы можем результат функции преобразовать к списку и соответственно работать с ним как со списком:

```
>>> print(list(split_time(4/4)))
[0.015625, 0.0625, 0.125, 0.00390625, 0.00390625, 0.125, 0.00390625, 0.0625, 0.5, 0.0078125, 0.015625, 0.03125, 0.00390625, 0.00390625, 0.015625, 0.00390625, 0.00390625, 0.0078125, 0.00390625]
```

Также можно пройтись циклом for без преобразования в список:

```
for d in split_time(4/4):
    print('1/%d' % (1/d), end=' ')  # Вместо вывода на печать можно играть ноту с нужной длительностью
    # print '1/%d' % (1/d),  # Вывод в Python2

# Вывод: 1/32 1/2 1/4 1/16 1/64 1/128 1/64 1/32 1/16 1/64 1/256 1/256
```

Сумма полученных чисел будет равна исходному числу (4/4 == 1.0):

```
>>> print(sum(split_time(4/4)))
1.0
```

**Ограничения функции:** предполагается, что первоначальное число будет целым числом или дробью со знаменателем, являющимся степенью двойки, но не больше 256 (например это будет что-то вроде 123/256). Если задать произвольное число, например 1.1, то функция зациклится.

Чтобы избежать зацикливания, можно слегка изменить функцию:

```
def split_time(t):
    while t > 0:
        d = t + 1 # Начальное число, заведомо попадающее в условие цикла
        while d > t:
            if t < 1.0 / 2**8:  # t<1/256
                d = t
                break

            d = 1.0 / 2**random.randint(0, 8)  # Случайная длительность от 1/1 до 1/256
        yield d
        t -= d
```

Тогда последнее число будет просто "остатком", не являющимся числом из ряда от 1/1 до 1/256. Для t=1.1 таким остатком будет число 0.002343750000000089

**Вариант реализации через дроби (fractions)**

Первоначальное значение задается как split_time(4, 4).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
from fractions import Fraction

def split_time(x, y):
    t = Fraction(x, y)
    while t > 0:
        d = t + 1  # Начальное число, заведомо попадающее в условие цикла
        while d > t:
            if t < Fraction(1, 2**8):
                d = t
                break
            d = Fraction(1, 2**random.randint(0, 8))  # Случайная длительность от 1/1 до 1/256
        yield d
        t -= d

print(list(split_time(4, 4)))

# [Fraction(1, 64), Fraction(1, 64), Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(1, 128), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 256), Fraction(1, 8), Fraction(1, 256), Fraction(1, 256), Fraction(1, 128), Fraction(1, 16), Fraction(1, 256)]

print(sum(split_time(7, 8)))  # Сумма полученных чисел равна первоначальной дроби

# 7/8

# Возможен перевод в человекопонятную форму через str()
for x in split_time(4, 4):
    print(str(x), end=' ')

# 1/32 1/256 1/128 1/256 1/64 1/8 1/64 1/4 1/32 1/64 1/16 1/4 1/8 1/64 1/128 1/32 1/128 

print()

# Возможен перевод в float 
for x in split_time(4, 4):
    print(float(x), end=' ')

# 0.25 0.0078125 0.125 0.25 0.125 0.0078125 0.0078125 0.0625 0.125 0.03125 0.0078125
```

---

По поводу ошибки: У вас рекурсия, по сути бесконечный цикл.

Во-первых, я бы посоветовал заменить рекурсию на, собственно, цикл while True (и вообще не советую использовать рекурсию в Python, кроме случаев, когда вы точно знаете, что она вам действительно нужна).

Во-вторых, делать загрузку файла только один раз - перед циклом, а не 100500 раз в цикле (в рекурсии). Если у вас несколько файлов - 8, например, - загрузите их в список, но, опять же, не загружайте их в каждой итерации цикла.

Код тестировался на Python 2.7.8 и Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Спасибо, очень подробно всё разъяснили. Но я чуть с ума не сошёл, пока не понял, что нужно поставить float(1) в строке d = 1 / 2**random.randint(0, 8)

Comment: @DanielDavis, у вас Python2, у меня код для Python3. Ответ сейчас поправлю. Вместо float(1) можно писать просто 1.0